# can some one please tell me about iqbals "ego"

Tags: reference-request

what ever you know about it ? he says that  the ultimate way to understand the purpose of one's existence on earth is by "khudi" (Persian word for self)

Comment: At this level of specificity you can just google "iqbal concept of ego" and go with it. Posts here are expected to give some idea of the poster's background, question's context and ask something more specific than "whatever you know about it".

Comment: i don't need to be educated how i should put my question or I require discipline how to put my question . please don't dictate me as well . i will grow and learn things in time . i will ask general questions as i want to ask generally.

Comment: You can ask as you want, but not if you also want to get answers here, see our [Help center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help).